# How to set mupdf-gl as a default application with a fixed resolution

Tags: pdf

I am using Linux Mint Tara (xfce). I would like to use mupdf-gl as a default application for viewing pdf files and automatically set 150 dpi as the resolution, i.e. when I double click a pdf file, it should be opened in mupdf-gl with the resolution set to 150 dpi. Currently it opens in mupdf-gl with the default resolution of 72 dpi. The resolution can be set on the command line as follows: mupdf-gl -r 150 FileToOpen.pdf but I don't know how to set it for files which are to be opened using the mouse.

Note that since mupdf-gl is not available in the repositories, I have downloaded the source files from mupdf.com and built it on my machine.

Comment: how did you tell xfce (or whatever) to associated PDFs with mupdf?

Comment: I right clicked on a pdf file in the file manager (thunar) -> open with another application -> use a custom command (in this case /usr/bin/mupdf-gl) and checked the box "use as default for this kind of file"

Comment: @SalilS.Kulkarni you can edit the custom command given in thunar to include the `-r 150` option itself and then check the box.

Comment: @PrathuBaronia Thanks for point it out. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can simply make a little wrapper script that applies your desired arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mupdf-gl -r 150 "$@"
```

and then save this code somewhere on the system (say to `/usr/bin/my-mupdf`), make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/bin/my-mupdf`), and then select the path to this wrapper script from the GUI (`/usr/bin/my-mupdf` instead of `/usr/bin/mupdf-gl`). This way the GUI calls your wrapper script which in turn replaces itself with `mupdf-gl` with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `alias` for `mupdf-gl`, like this:-

`$ alias mupdf-gl=mupdf-gl\ -r\ 150`

Be sure to include this line in your `/home/.bash_aliases` to avoid typing it again.

Comment: Does this alias also applies to files which will be opened by double clicking in the file manager or will be useful only for opening the files using the command lines

Comment: I checked, this does not work for mouse clicked files. Let me find a solution and update my answer.